# Allow non-root users to execute specific command

Tags: linux, bash, root

As in title - I'd like to allow non-root users to execute specific command, but not binary. Eg:

```
# killall sshd
```

but not allow to kill any process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use sudo. This command is very flexible and will permit you to specify the exact commands and users to be able to use escalated privileges

Answer (score 3):

You can add the user to `/etc/sudoers` (edited from `/etc/passwd`, that was a mistake)

// Enable user to run a command.

```
userxyz ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/lib/somecommand
```

// Enable user to run command, but restrict it to specific arguments.

```
zuerxyz ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/lib/command ARG1 ARG2 ARG3
```

I'm sure there's more you can do, but this should get you going.

Comment: You mean /etc/sudoers, right?